# 実行中のRubyコードの書き換えについて

Tags: ruby

初心な質問で申し訳ありませんが，わからないのでお答えいただければ幸いです．

Rubyで記述されたプログラムを実行したとします．
ここで，実行中のプログラムを書き換えたとします．
（シミュレーション条件など）
そうした場合，現在実行されているコードは，書き換え後のプログラムが反映されるのでしょうか．

Comment: 実際に試した結果はどうなりましたか？

Comment: @cubick 変わらないような気がします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

反映されないです。反映されるとしたら、例えば rails の development モードなどがそうですが、ファイルが変更されたら自動的にそれを読み込み直してロジックに反映するような機構をフレームワーク側がサポートしている場合に限ります。